# DC blocking in Audio amplifiers

Tags: audio, filter, signals, signal-processing, audio-processing

I am working with digital amplifiers and from what I can see there is a DC blocking filter that is placed at the start of the signal chain .My questions are split up as follows :

1. Why is this DC filter placed at the start of the signal chain ?

2.The cutoff frequency of this filter is just 4Hz Any intuition behind having a cut off as low as 4Hz

3. This filter is a Double Precision Filter . Any reason why DC blocking should be done with a Double Precision filter rather than a Single Precision Filter ?

Regards
Clauvunate

Comment: I think better to ask this question here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or ask at https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ My naive assumption is that it's first because it eliminates DC that would mess up further processing along the way. Start by cleaning up the signal to prevent garbage-in garbage-out processing. Cutoffs are usually dependent upon the slope, and a double precision would maybe have a sharper slope than single precision?